# How to write an integration test for service that uses ActiveMQ Artemis

Tags: java, automated-tests, integration-testing, activemq-artemis, amq

I am looking into automated integration tests for a service that consumes from and produces to Red Hat AMQ 7.5.0. I am aware that you can produce & consume via REST, but this service is part of a pipeline and once data is put on a queue, it is potentially quickly sent to the next step.

Is there a way to view or otherwise verify a message has passed through a queue? I would like to verify that specific messages were sent, or ideally some kind of JSON search would be awesome (i.e, search for messages that have gone through that had certain key/value pairs).

Comment: Updated with version

Comment: Preferrably a specific message but a message in general would be good as well

Comment: Did my answer address your comment? If so please mark it as correct to help other users who have this same question in the future. If not please elaborate as to what is lacking. Thanks!

Comment: @JustinBertram Actually haven't yet implemented for tests... we are in the process of moving to openshift with a logging stack so I have been waiting on that. Sorry for the delay!

Answer (score 0):

ActiveMQ Artemis (the broker shipped in Red Hat AMQ 7.x) doesn't keep historical data about messages that have already been consumed, and I don't know of any broker which does.

However, you could use the [`LoggingActiveMQServerPlugin`](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/broker-plugins.html#using-the-loggingactivemqserverplugin) to log details about the message to a file and then search through that file for the information you're looking for.